# Syntax error on line 46... Is 'return' or 'async' used incorrectly?

Tags: reactjs

Is the issue that I'm using return outside a function or am I just using async too many times/incorrectly?

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hubspot-5nk7ww

```
 // components/Form.js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export const FormHSNewsletter = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent form submit default behavior
    if (!name || !email) return; // if an input field is empty, don't submit the form
    const hubspot_response = await submit_hubspot_form(email, name);
    console.log(hubspot_response); // make sure it succeeded!
  };

  async function submit_hubspot_form(email, firstname) {
    const portalId = process.env.REACT_APP_HUBSPOT_PORTAL_ID;
    const formGuid = process.env.REACT_APP_HUBSPOT_NEWSLETTER_ID;
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    };

    const response = async (e) =>
      await axios.post(
        "https://api.hsforms.com/submissions/v3/integration/submit/${portalId}/${formGuid}",
        {
          portalId,
          formGuid,
          fields: [
            {
              name: "firstname",
              value: firstname
            },
            {
              name: "email",
              value: email
            }
          ]
        },
        config
      );
    return response;
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        className="home-textinput input"
        placeholder="First name"
        name="firstname"
        type="text"
        value={name}
        onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        className="home-textinput input"
        placeholder="email@domain.com"
        required="required"
        name="email"
        type="email"
        value={email}
        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
      />
      <br />
      <input
        type="submit"
        value="Subscribe"
        className="button-primary button"
      />
    </form>
  );
};

export default FormHSNewsletter;
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code directly in your post.

Comment: Could you specify, line 46 of which file and what is the error message? I couldn't find any error messages in your sandbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you had one bracket too many in this function removing the last } solved it because your return wasn't in the function/component ( the bracket closed it ) you also missed an install for axios but codepen should take care of that for you, happy coding!
[image]

Comment: The form isn't posting to HubSpot but his fixed the syntax issues and it looks like I had an extra semi-colon as well. Thanks @ChankanChan. 

I didn't add the axios dependency because I had it locally.